# Google CCS (GCM) - project not whitelisted

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, whitelist

I'm trying to get the Python code working that I found on:
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html
I've change the first 2 rows with (I think) the correct data.
The projectnr and api key is fake, it's just to show you how it almost looks.

```
import sys, json, xmpp
SERVER = ('gcm.googleapis.com', 5235)
USERNAME = '489713985816'
PASSWORD = 'AIzd237jjN_iT7yRxLWiHRreqax45XaMJQ6VJ98'
```

I've created a google api project (tried it with 2 different projects).
Activated GCM.
Copied the following:
Project Number: 489713985816
API key       : AIzd237jjN_iT7yRxLWiHRreqax45XaMJQ6VJ98
Tried the code with a Key for server, and a key for browser apps, both with and without a specific IP address.

When I execute the code with #python ccs.py I get the following result:
If this is my problem, how do I get my project whitelisted?

```
Invalid debugflag given: socket
DEBUG: 
DEBUG: Debug created for /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xmpp/client.py
DEBUG: flags defined: socket
DEBUG: socket       start Plugging <xmpp.transports.TCPsocket instance at 0x1ea2950> 
into     <xmpp.client.Client instance at 0x1ea27a0>
DEBUG: socket       start Successfully connected to remote 
host ('gcm.googleapis.com', 5235)
DEBUG: socket       sent  <?xml version='1.0'?>
<stream:stream xmlns="jabber:client" to="gcm.googleapis.com" version="1.0"
xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" >
DEBUG: socket       got   
<stream:stream from="gcm.googleapis.com" id="FD82304ADA8C8019" version="1.0"
xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
<stream:features>
<mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
<mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism>
<mechanism>X-GOOGLE-TOKEN</mechanism>
<mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism>
</mechanisms>
</stream:features>
DEBUG: socket       sent  <auth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"
mechanism="PLAIN">MjgzMVqTl9p\nVDdUTZWSjk4\n</auth>
DEBUG: socket       got <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
<temporary-auth-failure/>
<text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">
Project 489713985816 not whitelisted.</text>
</failure>
</stream:stream>
Authentication failed!
```

Comment: I think I know why I get the "Project not whitelisted".
The service is not open for public and you have to signup first: https://services.google.com/fb/forms/gcm/   I've signed up and update this ticket when ready.

Comment: Any luck?  I'm interested to see how long it's taking to approve new servers.  The new Google Cloud PHP hosting approved my request within 24hours.

Comment: No approval received after 10 days.

Comment: Do you find sollution to this problem?

Comment: I still haven't made progress, unlike @Gaston when I connect, instead of getting a 'project not whitelisted' message, I don't get any messages at all. Just silence, then disconnected after about 60 seconds.

Comment: @simbolo, now I can answer your question. It took 3 months ;)

Answer (score 3):

you might wan't to try the following guide http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

I was having the same problem that you are but following this guide has helped me get my push notifications through without having to sign up to be whitelisted.

Answer (score 3):

After 3 months of waiting, I've just received an email from a Google employee.
My GCM whitelist request has been approved.
Thank you Ashish.
Now, let the fun begin!

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation, it is mentioned several times that to use Up-stream messaging, you need to ask authorization (be whitelisted).

You can do that here: https://services.google.com/fb/forms/gcm/

You can still use the old "Cloud to device" messaging. [You can read more about this, including links to a sample project here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html).

Comment: I just tried signing up and I get: `Internal server error – 500`. Not cool.