# Project not whitelisted CCS(GCM)

Tags: android

I'm using java server to send message to use google cloud message. But when i sent message i've received " project **** not whitelisted"

i've signed up at https://services.google.com/fb/forms/gcm/ and received a confirm email with content "Thank you. Your information has been sent to Google. A member of the team will be in touch shortly."

but when i try to send message again still received "project **** not whitelisted"

who can tell me how long does it take to whitelisted by google?

Comment: `A member of the team will be in touch shortly.` means wait for approval.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can expect mail from Google withing certain period(May be 3 months) of time.But am not sure how much time it will take.These are the links that i found on the internet which may help you:

1.[Developer Console](https://developers.google.com/console/help/)

2.[Google user got mail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18283231/2110050)

3.[Discussion on Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-content-api-for-shopping/X-cCRuqyyN4)