# GCM Notification arrives after 30seconds

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am using Google development sample codes to receive GCM notifications. I have spent nearly a week to find why I receive notifications after 25~30 seconds!!! did not find any answer.
I receive other apps' notifications (such as Viber, Line and WhatsApp) almost instantly!
It has the same slow behaviour in both emulator and my Samsung Galaxy S5.

I receive respond with message ID from Google GCM server instantly when I send a notifications so it means the problem is from Google GCM server to my app.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: this solved my problem][this solved my problem][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259327/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-downstream-message-delay

Comment: How did you send the messages from your server? did you use http post?